# url_for or link_to in backend with admin generator Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, admin-generator

in backend_dev i generated with admin generator module News:

```
localhost/backend_dev.php/news/2/edit
```

this is link for edit News ID 2. How can i generate this link for other ID?

```
url_for('news/edit?id=2')
```

doesnt work, output is:

```
localhost/backend_dev.php/news/edit/action?id=1
```

In routing i have only:

```
news:
  class: sfDoctrineRouteCollection
  options:
    model:                News
    module:               News
    prefix_path:          /news
    column:               news_id
    with_wildcard_routes: true
```

Comment: have you defined a route for news/edit? if so can you post it

Comment: i have only: newss:
  class: sfDoctrineRouteCollection
  options:
    model:                News
    module:               News
    prefix_path:          /news
    column:               news_id
    with_wildcard_routes: true 

How can i make this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your route has defined the identifier column as `news_id`, so try changing your url creation to

`url_for('news/edit?news_id=2')`